# reflection dll comments

Tags: .net, reflection, dll

Is it possible to read the comments on the dll.
Comments are listed under Version when one looks at the property of the dll.

I know that i can get the version number but would rather get the comments as it is user friendly.

Assembly.GetName.Version.ToString --will give version number

thanks

Comment: You mean the comments that display when you right-click an assembly in Windows Explorer and then choose "Properties"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo`:

```
FileVersionInfo info = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(fileName);

Console.WriteLine("{0}, version {1}, comments: {2}", 
                   fileName, info.FileVersion, info.Comments);
```

This works for all kinds of dlls, not just .NET ones.

Comment: FYI i did the following
info.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location).Comments

Answer (score 0):

I know the Title, Subject, Keywords, Comments, etc. viewed in the Summary tab when you right-click a file is a feature called "Alternate Data Streams" (ADS) in Windows.  ADS is just the Microsoft name for a [filesystem fork](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(filesystem)).

You should be able to p-invoke to access ADS.  An example can be found at CodeProject [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/ads.aspx).  Microsoft has some example C code [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/105763).

--- EDIT ---

The comments you are seeing can be accessed via [FileVersionInfo.Comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.comments.aspx).  Here's an example of how to get that:

```
string comments = System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(
    @"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll")
```

The result is "Flavor=Retail", which is exactly what I see in the Comments under the file.

Comment: I m trying to read comments under version > Assembly version,comments,company,file version,internal name...product version.

Comment: OK, those Comments are stuff in the DLL's version resources.  If you open a DLL in the Visual Studio resource editor, you'll see wha t I mean.

For example, open mscorlib.dll in C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727 (or whatever version you like).  Expand the DLL name and Version folder.  Double-click on version info 1.  The version comes up, and the Comments information is under the block header English (United States).